# Git won't accept PAT, only Windows password - but Git LFS requires PAT

Tags: azure-devops

We have on-premises Azure DevOps and authentication for our Git repositories is linked to my Windows login - I can give my username and Windows password.

GitLFS 3.1 requires me to set up a PAT in DevOps which works, but I'm seeing some odd authentication conflict between Git and Git LFS on the same repo so I thought I'd just use my PAT for Git too. But when Git Credential Manager asks me for authentication for Git, it will not accept the PAT - only my Windows password.

Every time I provide authentication for git, this overrides saved git LFS credentials and vice versa. I'm constantly having to provide credentials! Is there a way to get git to use PAT as well - presumably this is an Azure DevOps issue, not a git issue?

Comment: What version of LFS, Git and Credential Manager do you have installed. LFS should be picking up the git credential manager creds just fine. How is the credential manager configured in your git config?

Comment: But I also see a bug tracking issues with LFS 3: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4853#issue-1123305913